# Why am I unable to get accelerometer values inside a Cocoa framework

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I am trying to create a framework for a partner company that accesses a devices accelerometer. I am coming from an Android background and iOS development is still very new to me, so I might miss something obvious. If that is important I am using Xcode 9, Swift 4 and an iPhone 6 Plus for tests.

The first thing I did was try out the basic CoreMotion tutorials to create very basic app, that just prints current accelerometer values to the console. It looks like:

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to:OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
            print("Getting Accelerometer Update")
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine.

If I take the same code and move it to a cocoa framework project it simply does nothing. The closure for `startAccelerometerUpdates` is never called. For this case the changed ViewController looks like:

**ViewController.swift inside the app project**

```
import UIKit
import DataCapturing

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let dc = DataCapturingService()
        dc.start()
    }
}
```

The class in my framework looks like:

**DataCapturingService.swift inside the DataCapturing framework**

```
import Foundation
import CoreMotion

public class DataCapturingService {

    private let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    public init() {

    }

    public func start() {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { data, error in
            print("Getting Accelerometer Update")
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any restrictions on accessing sensor hardware from inside a framework? Do I need to provide any permissions somehow? The documentation unfortunately does not tell anything about this (or I may be to dumb to find it).

EDIT: Interestingly if I inject the `CMMotionManager` from the app projects `ViewController` everything works fine btw. For this case the changed ViewController looks like:

**ViewController.swift inside the app project**

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
import DataCapturing

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        let dc = DataCapturingService(motionManager)
        dc.start()
    }
}
```

The class in my framework looks like:

**DataCapturingService.swift inside the DataCapturing framework**

```
import Foundation
import CoreMotion

public class DataCapturingService {

    private let motionManager

    public init(_ manager: CMMotionManager) {
        self.motionManager = manager
    }

    public func start() {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { data, error in
            print("Getting Accelerometer Update")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only printing `myData` if `data` is not `nil`. If you add `else { print("\(error)") }` does it print an error?

Comment: Hi, That was one thing I suspected, but no. Removing the `if`and only adding a simple `print("Test")`shows that the closure is never called.

Comment: 1 thing to double check with iOS development is that it runs on the main thread. If something fails silently that’s often the reason. Otherwise, make sure you keep your instance of DataCapturingService alive. If CMMotionManager deallocates it will probably stop sending notifications.

Comment: That could be the problem. Funny enough it seems that if I create the CMMotionManager inside the main app project and inject it into the DataCapturingService everything works fine. It is curious though that I am not calling the `start` method on a separate thread. It's just a static call from the `ViewController#viewDidAppear` method, so there should be no difference between the first and second variant.